# CPU Usage Percent Not Accurate compared to Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to get same results as Task manager for CPU Usage in percent. 
For memory I used this code and it seems that is working fine:

```
        ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
        {
            double TotalVisibleMemorySize = (Convert.ToDouble(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"])) / (1024 * 1024);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Visible Memory: {0} GB", (TotalVisibleMemorySize).ToString("0.0"));

            double FreePhysicalMemory = (Convert.ToDouble(result["FreePhysicalMemory"])) / (1024 * 1024);
            Console.WriteLine("Free Physical Memory: {0} GB", (FreePhysicalMemory).ToString("0.0"));

            double FreePhysicalMemoryPercent = (FreePhysicalMemory * 100) / TotalVisibleMemorySize;
            Console.WriteLine("Free Physical Memory: {0} %", (FreePhysicalMemoryPercent).ToString("0.0"));

            double UsedPhysicalMemory = TotalVisibleMemorySize - FreePhysicalMemory;
            Console.WriteLine("Used Physical Memory: {0} GB", (UsedPhysicalMemory).ToString("0.0"));

            double UsedPhysicalMemorypercent = 100 - FreePhysicalMemoryPercent;
            Console.WriteLine("Used Physical Memory: {0} %", (UsedPhysicalMemorypercent).ToString("0.0"));
        }
```

So with the same idea I tried for CPU. I know that this question was asked multiple times, but I did not find a correct solution for this that works.

I'm using the following code (I also tried _Total):

```
        wql = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor");
        searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
        results = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
        {
            var usage = obj["PercentProcessorTime"];
            var name = obj["Name"];
            Console.WriteLine(name + " : " + usage);
        }
```

Question: What is wrong with this code, how to correct it to work? Or what is the problem?

PS: I use these two code snippets in a m_procTimer_Tick event and the timer is set to 1000.

Comment: "I did not find a correct solution for this that works". You haven't explained why this code doesn't work. What's wrong with the output here?

Comment: The output from code:
0 : 0 |
1 : 0 |
2 : 0 |
3 : 6 |
4 : 0 |
5 : 0 | <- edited, it was 0
_Total : 1
The value for CPU utilization from Task manager:
8 %

Comment: I saw some solutions with PerformanceCounter : the NextValue() was called 2 times, in between a Thread.Sleep(1000). I tried also this code, but it froze the UI.